# Deploying a trained model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have trained my Neural Style transfer model and got .ckpt files after training. Now I want to deploy this model using tensorflow-serving. How can I proceed further ?

Answer (score 0):

Install Docker and Pull Docker Tensorflow serving image.

$docker pull tensorflow/serving

copy your SavedModel to the container's model folder:

$docker cp models/ serving_base:/models/

Follow instructions from https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/g3doc/docker.md , and you should be able to run serving image to host model.

Check onto below link for more details - 
https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker